# 403 error when testing Flask API using Post method to send JSON data

Tags: flask, python-requests

API looks like this

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/mycalculator', methods = ['POST'])
def json_example():
    req_data = request.get_json()
    #..... did a bunch of computation 
    return response
```

My API testing code look like:

```
import requests
import json

URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/mycalculator/"
def test_jsonget_guideline():
    file =  open('myjsonfile', 'r')
    json_input = file.read()    
    request_json = json.loads(json_input)
    print(request_json)

    # make post request within json input body
    response = requests.post(url=URL, 
                             data=request_json)                         
    if response.ok:
        print(response.content)
    else:
        print("response not okay. status code: {}".format(response.status_code))
```

I keep getting the error like this:

```
status code: 403
```

I was able to test this JSON file **using Postman**. But I want to write a python script to automate all the testings. Anyone know which step I am not doing right? I looked through many tutorial videos, but I was not able to fix this problem. 
I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Hello! May I know how you fixed the issue?  I'm currently facing the same issue with requests.post(). I've tried using requests.post(url=URL, json=request_json) instead but I'm still facing the same error. Appreciate if you can share how you manage to fixed the issue! Thank you! :)

Comment: @OinkOink It turns out to be the proxy issue. Because my company network has firewalls... I just specified the proxy and then connection is okay.